# Getting error Unexpected value 'undefined' declared by the module 'DynamicTestModule'

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-test

I have checked few answers in Stack Overflow, but I am not able to solve my issue

Here is my code for Spec file

```
    import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
    import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';
    import { MatMenuModule} from '@angular/material/menu';
    import { DashboardModule } from './dashboard.module';
    import { DataService } from 'src/app/shared/data.service';




    describe('DashboardComponent.forRoot()', () => {
      let component: DashboardComponent;
      let fixture: ComponentFixture<DashboardComponent>;
      let menu: MatMenuModule;

      beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          imports:[
              DashboardModule.forRoot()
            ],
          declarations: [ DashboardComponent, menu ]
        })
        .compileComponents();
      }));

      beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DashboardComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
      });

      it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
      });
      it(`should not provide 'DataService' service`, () => {
        expect(() => TestBed.get(DataService)).toThrowError(/No provider for/);
        });
    });
```

I am getting below error

```
Failed: Unexpected value 'undefined' declared by the module 'DynamicTestModule'
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: `menu` is undefined. Did you want to use `MatMenuModule` instead?

Comment: @yurzui Menu i have declared in declaration right

Comment: Yep. but you haven't assigned it to anything

Comment: ok I removed that but still I am getting the same error 

Failed: Unexpected value 'undefined' declared by the module 'DynamicTestModule'